# Send static images from an iOS app to a Chromecast?

Tags: ios, chromecast

I don't want to send video; I want to send a static image to a Chromecast from an iOS app. I haven't seen any indication that this is possible...but it doesn't seem like it'd be impossible either.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Comment: Google has a SDK for [chromecast iOS](https://developers.google.com/cast/downloads/) also few sample code on this [github repo](https://github.com/googlecast). You can explore that further.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say that you want to display images instead of videos.

So you need to do 2 changes,

1. from sender app, replace video URI by your Image URI
2. In receiver.html file make following changes.

earlier receiver file contains

```
<video id="vid"
       style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%">
<div id="status" style="display:none; font-size:300%; position:absolute;top:40%;left:40%;">
  <img src="/images/chrome_loading.gif" width="60%">
</div>
```

change it to

```
<body>
     <img id="vid" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%"/>
</body>
```